# spring boot security custom login form

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to create my own custom login form using spring boot security:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.9.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

In the front-end side I created this login form:

```
<br/>
<form action="j_spring_security_check" method="post" name="login" id="login">

    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" name="username">
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <span class="input-group-addon">PWD</span>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Clave" name="password">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
    <br/>       
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Acceder">
    </div>
</form>
```

In the back-end:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/index.html", "/bootstrap/**", "/jquery/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.html").passwordParameter("password").usernameParameter("username")
                .permitAll()                    
                .and().logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

}
```

I took some ideas from this post: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example

And my problem is when I login it never redirects me to the previously requested page and continously displays in the login form.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 2):

I know its late. But may be useful for some others

change `action="j_spring_security_check"` to `login.html` as you have defined `loginPage("/login.html")`(overriding the `j_spring_security_check`) in configure method. It should work

Comment: Thaks for your reply. I finally used spring mvc in order to not get stuck into this point. Probably within a couple of weeks I will have to use this solution again. If so, I will test this and will let you know the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The default login processing URL is /login (not /j_spring_security_*). Probably you are just submitting the form to the wrong place?

Comment: Hi Dave, in case I use /login I get error 404. In the example included in the web I pasted it is using the same as me.

Comment: That sample is using XML config (it's different). 404 is different at least. Maybe you actually authenticated a missing resource?

Answer (score 0):

```
use front end like 

<div class="login-page">
        <div class="form">
            <form:form method="POST" action="${contextPath}/login"
                class="login-form" modelAttribute="user">
                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                    value="${_csrf.token}" />


                <form:input path="username" type="text" id="inputUserName"
                    placeholder="User Name" />
                <span><form:errors cssClass="error" path="username" /></span>

                <form:input path="password" type="password" id="inputPassword"
                    placeholder="Password" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-group btn-default btn-animated">Log
                    In</button>
                <p class="message">
                    Not registered? <a href="register">Create an account</a>
                </p>
            </form:form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

then **back end as**

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


     http
     .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/register").permitAll()
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
         .formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome", true)
         .loginPage("/login")
         .permitAll()
         .and()
         .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
         .permitAll();

}
```

the whole code is here on **Github** [Spring boot security](https://github.com/balakoder/spring-boot-security)